# Support level for Dojo 1.8.1

Tags: dojo

What is the support for Dojo community support for Dojo 1.8.1 framework?

Our application use Dojo 1.8.1. What is the impact if we are advised to move to the latest framework ?

Answer (score 0):

Dojo 1.x is pretty much "dead" in the sense that only minor maintenance is done.
Migrating to Dojo 2.x or higher from 1.x is not easy, as there is no out of the box migration path.

Of course you can wrap your Dojo 1.x widgets in Dojo 2.x, but then what's the point of using Dojo? Then you can also use another (more widely used) framework.

I don't want to bash on Dojo, as we use it extensively (and successfully) in our company, but the fact that there is no easy migration path to Dojo 2.x makes us want to transition into a more common framework eventually.

More information can be found here: https://github.com/dojo/dojo.io/issues/153